# Alternative to logical OR, where false is treated as truthy?

Tags: ruby

So I have some code that gets values from a couple sources in a fixed priority order. It looks like this:

```
{   foo: true
    bar: 42
}.each_pair do |attrib,default|
    instance_variable_set :"@#{attrib}",data[attrib] || template[attrib] || otherdata[attrib] || default
end
```

As you can probably tell, trying to override a true default with false won't work. How would I fix this without creating a horrible mess? (I do know how to fix it *with a horrible mess*, but I'm fairly certain there is something nice in the standard library for this exact situation, I just don't remember what it is called and can't think of a good search term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the first non-`nil` value:

```
instance_variable_set :"@#{attrib}", [ data[attrib], template[attrib], otherdata[attrib], default ].compact.first
```

Not the most efficient method, but gets the job done and works well if not exercised aggressively.

A slightly more forgiving version:

```
instance_variable_set :"@#{attrib}", [ data[attrib], template[attrib], otherdata[attrib], default ].find { |v| !v.nil? }
```

This scans for the first non-`nil` value and returns that. It doesn't produce an intermediate array like `compact` does.

What you really want is a more forgiving method:

```
def instance_variable_set_from(attrib, *sources)
  instance_variable_set(:"@#{attrib}", sources.find { |v| !v.nil? }
end
```

Which is more self-explanatory when used:

```
instance_variable_set_from(attrib, data[attrib], template[attrib], otherdata[attrib], default)
```

Comment: Doesn't really give the same short-circuit evaluation, but is a lot cleaner than anything I had in mind. Hash lookups are plenty fast, so it's fine

Comment: Yeah, the alternative is `data[attrib].nil? ? template[attrib].nil? ? ... : template[attrib] : data[attrib]` which is really not that readable. There was talk of Ruby introducing a `//` operator that does the same as `||` but only on `nil`, not sure where that got to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `data`, `template` and `otherdata` are all hashes, you could use [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-fetch). It returns the value if it is contained in the hash, or the block's result otherwise:

```
value = data.fetch(attrib) { template.fetch(attrib) { otherdata.fetch(attrib, default) } }

instance_variable_set :"@#{attrib}", value
```

or alternatively [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) the first hash containing the key and `fetch` its result, falling back to `default`:

```
value = [data, template, other_data].find { |h| h.key?(attrib) }.fetch(attrib, default)
```

Note that this would also allow `nil` values.